# IE9 - asp.net cannot access cookie created for my domain by third party site

Tags: cookies, internet-explorer-9

I have this weird problem in IE 9. I have a site which allows a user to login and can also be logged in by a separate website using web service in the background. When logged in, a cookie is created. In fiddler, I can see the user has logged in to my site from the third party website and the cookie is created. The third party site makes an ajax call and the cookie is created in my domain.

But when I click on a link to my site from the third party site, the login page is displayed again. I wrote a debug code that states in the page that the cookie does not exist but I can see in IE settings that the cookie does exist. The cookie expires in 24 hours.

How do I fix it? By the way, it works fine in most other browsers including IE8, IE7, Chrome.

This is similar to - [IE9 Separate cookies for third party request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895558/ie9-separate-cookies-for-third-party-request) - but there is no response there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation introduced in IE 9+. It isolates different zones to access each others' data. For example if a cookie is created in example.com for domain:example.com, a.example.com cannot access the cookie if their zones are different (one is intranet, one is trusted, etc.). You can check the zones in Internet Option -> Security tab.

For more information check [Cookie Sharing in Cross-Zone Scenarios](http://bit.ly/15aSlUV)